# Determine the last 7 days backup size

Tags: shell-script, files

Consider I have a folder `/home/abdul/backup` which contains `.gz` file for the past 1 year...My requirement is to get the size of last 7 days...

Answer (score 7):

```
find /home/abdul/backup -daystart -name '*.gz' -mtime -7 -exec du -h '{}' ';'
```

How it works:

`find` - does what it says on the tin; since you didn't specify which operating system you are using, I'm assuming here that you have access to GNU find.

`/home/abdul/backup` - starting directory

`-daystart` - measure times since the start of the day (may or may not be what you want)

`-name '*.gz'` - only consider files with names ending in `.gz` (or more accurately, matching `*.gz`)

`-mtime -7` - file modification time within the last **7***24 hours, taking -daystart into account

`-exec du -h '{}' ';'` - execute `du` to print the size of the named file, in human-readable units (`{}` expands to the file name in question)

This will list all files which have been *modified* in the last 7 days. Depending on which exact OS and file system you are running it might be possible to base a check on the file's creation time, but many *nix systems don't keep track of the time when a file was initially created, or "born".

Comment: Change the `';'` to `+` and add the `-s` option to `du` to get a total.

Comment: @jordanm It doesn't seem to work for me; I still get a list executing `find ~ -daystart -mtime 7 -exec du -sh '{}' '+'`. Am I missing something?

Comment: You also need `-mtime -7` don't you? On my system at least,`-mtime 7` will only match files modified _exactly_ 7 days ago.

Comment: @terdon Ooh, right, good catch. Will edit, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @jordanm, the `+` will pass as many parameters as it can to a single `du` process, each as a separate argument, which meand the `du` will still output a result for every file. To accomplish the summary use [`--files0-from=- -hsc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134245/total-size-of-group-of-files-selected-with-find)

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -ctime -7 | xargs ls -l | awk '{ TOTAL += $5;} END{print TOTAL;}'
```

This will first list files with less than 7*24 hours in the current directory, get their size in bytes, sum it up and provide you the result.

Comment: My find's man page says `-atime` is to match based on "File was last accessed n*24 hours ago.". Is yours different?

Comment: Indeed, i've been a bit too fast. this you be using either -ctime or -mtime depending on how his backup solution works with file rotation/stacking.
And he's also not explicitely asking for a sum of the sizes.

Comment: [Don't parse the output of `ls`.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Answer (score 2):

If your file names do not contain spaces or other weird characters, you could just do this:

```
du -sch "$(find /home/abdul/backup -name '*.gz' -mtime +7) "
```

For spaces and other strange characters, use this instead:

```
find /home/abdul/backup -name '*.gz' -mtime -7 -print0 | xargs -0 du -sch
```

If you have a *lot* of files that match your criteria both of the commands above will fail. The first because the file list is too long and the second because `xargs` will split into multiple commands and return the total for each subset.

Another solution that avoids these problems is (thanks to Paulo Almeida whose [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83364/determine-the-last-7-days-backup-size/83378?noredirect=1#comment123719_83367) mentioned it):

```
find /home/abdul/backup -name '*.gz' -mtime -7 -print0 | du -sch --files0-from -
```

From `man du`:

```
  --files0-from=F
          summarize  disk  usage  of  the NUL-terminated
          file names specified in file F; If F is - then
          read names from standard input
```

Comment: The first one fails on my $HOME with "Argument list too long" and the second doesn't produce the total.

Comment: @Paolo, yes that will happen if there are too many files. See updated answer, and thanks for the hint :).